# Nested Menu Options

Tags: android, android-studio, submenu

After around 5+ hours of code fiddling and searching I finally decided to create an account so I could ask my question. I have found a lot of similar things but not quite what i am looking for, I want to create a menu, in a navigation drawer, that uses collapsed menus. [Such as this Image Demonstrates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCjdm.png) that when you click on an option it changes the menu to a list of options in that menu. I don't need an elaborate explanation just the View Object(or what ever it is).

Comment: what have you attempted in order to do what you want to do?

Comment: ExpandableListView, previous options stay visible on the page. Spinner, opens options in a new frame/window. The XML menu code, as far as I could see there is not way to collapse menu items, possible so visibility manipulation could work but I could not figure that out. It might be possible with one of the aforementioned things but I am not the most skill when it comes to programming androids, seeing as I started Java and Android Studio less than a week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Fragment` for each drill down. You could make the solution generic removing the need for a different fragment per drill down. Upon user selection replace the fragment. You could even bind animations to the transition as well.

Comment: Thanks, no clue if that will work, I have not yet done really any work with fragments but, it seems like it should, Thank you very much.

Comment: It will definitely work. Make the fragment contain a list with the row items you want and then use it as a listview.
A fragment is just a container for similar lifecycle methods as an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExpandableListView` for more [check](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the previous choices Such as if the menu said "A, B, or C" and you press "A" it changes the display to say "Ai, Aii or Aiii" from what i saw with my own test and from reading other users questions it only creates a "drill-down" style menu rather than replacing the original.

Comment: @JohnAdams If i have understand correctly, You need to show separate screen for each selection, right? In this case User Fragment where each Fragment will holds your choice of List Items. Say Fragment "first" holds "A,B,C" and Fragment "Second" holds "Ai, Aii, Aiii" like wise.